# Convert a symbol to its 4 digit unicode escape representation and vice versa

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

1) How can I convert a symbol to its 4 digit Unicode escape representation in python 2.7
e.g `"¥"` to `"\u00a5"`?

2) How can I convert a Unicode representation to the symbol notation on Windows 7/8 platform
e.g `"\u00a5"` to `"¥"`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Does it need to be `\u`-escaped? Will `\x` work? If so, try the `unicode_escape` codec. Otherwise, you can convert using the function below:

```
def four_digit_escape(string):
    return u''.join(char if 32 <= ord(char) <= 126 else u'\\u%04x'%ord(char) for char in string)

symbol = u"hello ¥"
print symbol.encode('unicode_escape')
print four_digit_escape(symbol)
```

2) Similarly, you can use the `unicode_escape` codec:

```
encoded_symbol = '\\u00a5'
print encoded_symbol
print encoded_symbol.decode('unicode_escape')
```

Comment: My answer assumes that you are following the best practice known as the "unicode sandwich." That is, you converted `symbol` to a unicode string when you created it or read it in. See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way I found to do this in python is to first decode it into unicode, get the `ord` of the unicode character and plug that into a format string. It looks like this:

```
"\\u%04x" % ord("¥".decode("utf-8"))
```

There is also a method `unichr` that is supposed to output something like this, but on my system it displays a different encoding than what the op wanted. So the above solution is the most platform independent way that I can think of.

Comment: Gives this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: That means that utf-8 is not the format that you have the string data in. You can try `.decode(sys.stdout.encoding)` to pick your local format. Otherwise you will just need to try to decode from different formats to find what works.