# Difficulty converting escaped UTF-8 using Python

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, codec

I can't understand why one function works and the other doesn't. I have tried encoding the aristotle.txt file as utf-8 and other encodings, but still it only outputs the escaped codes. Code as seen below.

```
import codecs

def convert_to_utf8_1(from_file, to_file):
    to_file = codecs.open(to_file,'w','utf8')
    from_file = codecs.open(from_file, 'r', 'utf8') 
    #from_file = open(from_file, 'r') 

    for line in from_file:
        to_file.write(line)
    to_file.close()

def convert_to_utf8_2(from_string, to_file):
    to_file = codecs.open(to_file,'w','utf8')
    to_file.write(from_string)
    to_file.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     a = "Aristotle$$$$Aristotle (/\u02C8\u00E6r\u026A\u02CCst\u0252t\u0259l/; Greek: \u1F08\u03C1\u03B9\u03C3\u03C4\u03BF\u03C4\u03AD\u03BB\u03B7\u03C2 [aristot\u00E9l\u025B\u02D0s], Aristot\u00E9l\u0113s; 384 \u2013 322 BCE) was a Greek philosopher and scientist born in Stagirus, northern Greece, in 384 BCE. His father, Nicomachus, died when Aristotle was a child, whereafter Proxenus of Atarneus became his guardian. At eighteen, he joined Plato's Academy in Athens and remained there until the age of thirty-seven (c. 347 BCE)."
     convert_to_utf8_1("aristotle.txt", "test1.txt")
     convert_to_utf8_2(a, "test2.txt")


#########################OUTPUT FROM test1.txt###############################
#Aristotle$$$$Aristotle (/\u02C8\u00E6r\u026A\u02CCst\u0252t\u0259l/; Greek: #\u1F08\u03C1\u03B9\u03C3\u03C4\u03BF\u03C4\u03AD\u03BB\u03B7\u03C2 [aristot\u00E9l\u025B\u02D0s], Aristot\u00E9l\u0113s; 384 #\u2013 322 BCE) was a Greek philosopher and scientist born in Stagirus, northern Greece, in 384 BCE. His father, Nicomachus, died #when Aristotle was a child, whereafter Proxenus of Atarneus became his guardian. At eighteen, he joined Plato's Academy in Athens #and remained there until the age of thirty-seven (c. 347 BCE).
#########################OUTPUT FROM test2.txt###############################
#Aristotle$$$$Aristotle (/ˈærɪˌstɒtəl/; Greek: Ἀριστοτέλης [aristotélɛːs], Aristotélēs; 384 – 322 BCE) was a Greek philosopher and #scientist born in Stagirus, northern Greece, in 384 BCE. His father, Nicomachus, died when Aristotle was a child, whereafter #Proxenus of Atarneus became his guardian. At eighteen, he joined Plato's Academy in Athens and remained there until the age of #thirty-seven (c. 347 BCE).
```

Hex of a few lines as requested:

```
0000-0010:  41 72 69 73-74 6f 74 6c-65 24 24 24-24 41 72 69  Aristotl e$$$$Ari
0000-0020:  73 74 6f 74-6c 65 20 28-2f 5c 75 30-32 43 38 5c  stotle.( /\u02C8\
```

Comment: What do the actual bytes in the file look like? Just a few (non-ASCII) characters in hex should suffice

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the input is valid UTF-8 but if it isn't, well, then -- garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Does the file `aristotle.txt` use the escaped characters? If yes, then there is your problem. The `codecs` functions don't magically convert those.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a symbol to it's 4 digit unicode escape representation and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028115/convert-a-symbol-to-its-4-digit-unicode-escape-representation-and-vice-versa)

Comment: I have saved the file with utf-8 encoding using sublime and notepad+.

Comment: The aristotle.txt file's contents are exactly the same as the string store in variable 'a'  The file does use those escaped characters. How do I fixed this then?

Comment: The proposed duplicate explains that exactly.  But the fundamental mistake here is that you assume that the source of your Python program is parsed exactly the same way as a file you read in a program; it is not.

Comment: Use the `unicode_escape` codec to read the file.

Comment: @triplee - The duplicate shows how to convert a single unicode character but doesn't explain why the exact same text saved in a file and in a variable produce different output when saved to a file. Even when the aristotle.txt file is saved with utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Just like `\t` stands for the two characters backslash and tee in a file, but represent a tab in a Python string. Your variable would be equivalent to the bytes in the file if you used a `r'...'` raw string, but you don't.